# how to view content of data set in packages in r?

Tags: r, dataset

I am very new in R.I want to see the content of data set in r packages.
For example

In the case of "arules" package .I want to see the content of dataset Adult.

I tried with following codes.But not working

```
library("arules")
data(Adult)
View(Adult)
```

its not working.

and also

```
data(Adult)
Adult<-as("Adult",matrix)
```

??

Answer (score 2):

After loading the data (`data(Adult)`) you can just write `Adult` to see the entire data set. If the dataset is large, you could also write `head(Adult)` or `tail(Adult)` to look at the 10 first or last rows of the dataset, respectively. `summary(Adult)` gives you a summary of the dataset. `str(Adult)` shows the structure, i.e. in what format various entries are stored.

Answer (score 0):

use

Adult<-as(Adult,"matrix").

Answer (score 0):

The dataset Adult is a special dataset defined by the author of arules.

```
> library("arules")
> data(Adult)
> class(Adult)
[1] "transactions"
attr(,"package")
[1] "arules"
> str(Adult)
Formal class 'transactions' [package "arules"] with 4 slots
  ..@ transactionInfo:'data.frame': 48842 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ transactionID: Factor w/ 48842 levels "1","10","100",..: 1 11112 22223 33334    43288 44399 45510 46621 47732 2 ...
  ..@ data           :Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:612200] 1 10 25 32 35 50 59 61 63 65 ...
  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:48843] 0 13 26 39 52 65 78 91 104 117 ...
  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 115 48842
  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
  ..@ itemInfo       :'data.frame': 115 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ labels   :Class 'AsIs'  chr [1:115] "age=Young" "age=Middle-aged" "age=Senior"   "age=Old" ...
  .. ..$ variables: Factor w/ 13 levels "age","capital-gain",..: 1 1 1 1 13 13 13 13 13  13 ...
  .. ..$ levels   : Factor w/ 112 levels "10th","11th",..: 111 63 92 69 30 54 65 82 90   91 ...
  ..@ itemsetInfo    :'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
```

If you want to see the content of Adult, you can use this:

```
> aa <- Adult@data
> class(aa)
[1] "ngCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
> str(aa)
Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:612200] 1 10 25 32 35 50 59 61 63 65 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:48843] 0 13 26 39 52 65 78 91 104 117 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 115 48842
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ factors : list() 
> dim(aa)
[1]   115 48842
> aa[1:5,1:5]
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . .
[2,] | . | . |
[3,] . | . | .
[4,] . . . . .
[5,] . . . . .
```